# Error when using a String as Range (VBA Excel)

Tags: string, excel, vba, range

I am trying to use a string to select some cells by using Range(MaPlage), but this doesn't work. Here is the code and how I constructed the string:

```
Dim MaPlage As String
Dim MyRange As Range
Dim Line As Integer
Dim AdrRD as String
Dim First_Cell As Boolean

First_Cell = True
AdrRD = "A"

For Line = 1 To 100 Step 1
If Sheet.Range(AdrRD & Line).Value = "" Then
    If First_Cell = True Then
        MaPlage = AdrRD & Line
        First_Cell = False
    Else
        MaPlage = MaPlage & ", " & AdrRD & Line
    End If
End If

Next Line

If MaPlage <> "" Then   
    Range(MaPlage).Select
    Selection.EntireRow.Delete
End If
```

There is an error at "Range(MaPlage).Select"

I have also tried Set MyRange = Range(MaPlage) but it gives me the same error.

Excel gives me the error in French but it's something like: "Error 1004: The 'Range' method from the object '_Global' has failed."

Thanks a lot!

EDIT: I just tried with

```
For Line = 1 To 40 Step 1
```

Instead of 100, and it worked correctly. Does this mean that when the selection goes all the way to line 100 it is to big ?

Comment: When your code halts, hover the cursor over the word `MaPlage` and see what the value is. Basic debugging will solve this issue for you.

Comment: I often do that, and in this piece of code it looks like `MaPlage` is just fine! It's just that when it's too long it doesn't show the end, but that doesn't mean that the program handles it as it is shown, does it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would appear [maximum address length in Excel is 255](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/7546f763-26c3-4b37-a2bd-f41254a6187f/max-length-of-address-string-as-parameter-to-getrange-method?forum=exceldev) characters.

However you [almost never need](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10714251/11683) to build an address as a string.

```
Dim MyRange As Range
Dim c As Range
Dim Line As Long

For Line = 1 To 100
  Set c = Sheet.Cells(Line, "A")
  If Len(c.Value) = 0 Then
    If MyRange Is Nothing Then
        Set MyRange = c
    Else
        Set MyRange = Application.Union(MyRange, c)
    End If
  End If
Next

MyRange.EntireRow.Delete
```

Depending on the size of the sheet's `UsedRange` and your needs, you might get away with simply doing

```
Sheet.Range("A1:A100").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
```

but this can raise an error if it doesn't find any cells, and it can cause the `SelectionChange` event to fire for no reason (Excel bug IMO).

Comment: Thanks, it works perfectly! I didn't know that there was a maximum size for strings.

Comment: Not for strings in general, only the range addresses.